# Strongloop - Execute PHP with model.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to execute PHP within a loopback model. When visiting [myapi:3000/api/Door/open](http://#) I'd like it to run the PHP file containing a function.

I have the /Door/open added as a remote method and it shows up in swagger.ui, the api returns "message": "createElement is not defined", even though jquery is included.

Here is my doors.js showing the remote method setup:

```
  module.exports = function(Door) {
  Door.open = function(id, cb) {
    var script = createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://192.168.10.139/Facility/doorfunc_dynamic.php?dpip=192.168.10.249&doorid=3&func=unlock"
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
  Door.remoteMethod(
    'open',
    { 
      description: 'Open a door by id',
      accepts: {args: 'id', type: 'number', name: 'id', description: 'Door id'},
      returns: {arg: 'open', type: 'string'},
      http: {path: '/open', verb: 'get'}       
    }
  );
};
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?
I have tried adding a static page within the client folder, however it does not show within the swagger.ui explorer.

Comment: are your importing jQuery as a package in your model.js?

Comment: Yes. All I want to do is go to myapi:3000/api/Door/open and run my PHP script. I have looked at editing the middleware.js, server.js and model.js..with no luck

Comment: just want to make sure if you are using jquery to perform http request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform only http request, you can use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package.

```
var request = require('request');
module.exports = function(Door) {
    Door.open = function(id, cb) {
        request('http://192.168.10.139/Facility/doorfunc_dynamic.php?dpip=192.168.10.249&doorid=3&func=unlock', 
            function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(body);
                }
        });
    };
    Door.remoteMethod(
        'open',
        { 
            description: 'Open a door by id',
            accepts: {args: 'id', type: 'number', name: 'id', description: 'Door id'},
            returns: {arg: 'open', type: 'string'},
            http: {path: '/open', verb: 'get'}       
        }
      );
    };
```

Hope it solves your problem.